# How to write test class for the following API Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, code-coverage

Hi I have a following rest api class. Can any body please advise how to write test class for the below.

```
global class ZyncAPI {
    public CarePlanWrapper getZyncData() {
        // Instantiate a new http object        
        Http h = new Http();        
        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        String endUrl = 'http://callout.com';
        req.setEndpoint(endUrl);
        system.debug(endUrl);   
        req.setMethod('GET');        
        // Send the request, and return a response        
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        system.debug(res.getBody());
        //List<HealthCloudGA__EhrCondition__c> patientCondition = new List<HealthCloudGA__EhrCondition__c>();
        //HealthCloudGA__EhrCondition__c Ehrpatientcondition;                               

        //ZyncJSONWrapper zyncresponse = new ZyncJSONWrapper();
        //List<ZyncJSONWrapper> zyncresponseData = new List<ZyncJSONWrapper>();
        //I tried the below one and zyncresponse.Action also still the same. 
        CarePlanWrapper PlanWrapper = new CarePlanWrapper();
        PlanWrapper = CarePlanWrapper.parse(res.getbody());
        system.debug(PlanWrapper);

        Map<string,List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c>> ProblemGoalMap = new Map<string,List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c>>();
        Map<string,List<Interventions__c>> GoalIntervensionMap = new Map<string,List<Interventions__c>>();
        Map<string,List<Task>> IntervensionTaskMap = new Map<string,List<Task>>();


        List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c> patientProblem = new List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c>();



        for(CarePlanWrapper.cls_entry entry : PlanWrapper.entry){
            List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c> GoalsList = new List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c>();
            for(CarePlanWrapper.cls_action actionRec : entry.resource.action){
                HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c cpgoal = new HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c();
                cpgoal.Name = actionRec.Title;
                GoalsList.add(cpGoal);
                List<Interventions__c> intervensionList = new List<Interventions__c>();
                for(CarePlanWrapper.cls_action goal : actionRec.action){
                    Interventions__c intervension = new Interventions__c();
                    if(goal.title != Null && goal.title.length() > 80)
                        intervension.Name = goal.Title.substring(0,80);
                    else
                        intervension.Name = goal.Title;
                    intervension.Title__c = goal.Title;
                    intervensionList.add(Intervension);
                    if(goal.action != Null){
                        List<task> taskList = new List<Task>();
                        for(CarePlanWrapper.Cls_Action task : goal.action){
                            task tsk = new Task();
                            tsk.Subject = task.title;
                            tsk.priority = 'Medium';
                            tsk.status = 'Not started';
                            taskList.add(tsk);
                        }
                        IntervensionTaskMap.put(entry.Resource.Title+actionRec.Title+goal.Title,TaskList);
                    }
                }                
                GoalIntervensionMap.put(entry.Resource.Title+actionRec.Title,intervensionList);
            }
            HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c cpproblem = new HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c();
            cpproblem.Name = entry.Resource.Title;
            patientProblem.add(cpproblem);
            ProblemGoalMap.put(entry.Resource.Title,GoalsList);
        }
        system.debug(ProblemGoalMap);
        system.debug(GoalIntervensionMap);
        System.debug(IntervensionTaskMap);

        system.debug(ProblemGoalMap.KeySet().size());
        system.debug(GoalIntervensionMap.Keyset().size());
        system.debug(IntervensionTaskMap.keyset().size());



        Map<string,string> ProblemIdMap = new Map<string,string>();
        Map<string,string> GoalIdMap = new Map<string,string>();
        List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c> GoalUpdateList = new List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c>();

        if(patientProblem.size() > 0)
            upsert patientProblem;

        for(HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c Problem : patientProblem){
            ProblemIdMap.put(problem.Name,Problem.id);
        }    

        for(string Plan : ProblemGoalMap.Keyset()){
            for(HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c goal : ProblemGoalMap.get(plan)){
                goal.HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c = ProblemIdMap.get(plan);
                GoalUpdateList.add(goal);
            }
        }

        if(GoalUpdateList.size() > 0)
            upsert GoalUpdateList;

        for(HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c goal : [select id,name,HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__r.Name from HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c where id IN: GoalUpdateList]){
            GoalIdMap.put(goal.HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__r.Name+goal.Name,goal.id);
        }

        List<Interventions__c> InterventionUpdateList = new List<Interventions__c>();
        for(string intervension : GoalIntervensionMap.Keyset()){
            for(Interventions__c inter : GoalIntervensionMap.get(intervension)){
                inter.Goal__c = GoalIdMap.get(intervension);
                InterventionUpdateList.add(inter);
            }
        }

        if(InterventionUpdateList.size() > 0)
            upsert InterventionUpdateList;
        Map<string,string> IntervesionIdMap = new Map<string,string>();
        for(Interventions__c inter : [select id,Title__c,Goal__r.Name,Goal__r.HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__r.Name from Interventions__c where id in: InterventionUpdateList]){
            IntervesionIdMap.put(inter.Goal__r.HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__r.Name+inter.goal__r.name+inter.Title__c,inter.id);
        }  

        system.debug(IntervesionIdMap.Keyset());
        system.debug(IntervensionTaskMap.keySet());

        for(string s : IntervesionIdMap.Keyset()){
            system.debug(s);
        }

        List<task> TaskUpdateList = new List<task>();
        for(string taskString : IntervensionTaskMap.keySet()){
            for(Task tsk : IntervensionTaskMap.get(taskString)){
                tsk.whatId = IntervesionIdMap.get(taskString);
                TaskUpdateList.add(tsk);
            }
        }  

        system.debug(TaskUpdateList[0]);

        if(TaskUpdateList.size() > 0)
            Upsert TaskUpdateList;

       try{
            if(res.getStatusCode() == 200)
            {

            }
        }
        catch(exception e){}
        return PlanWrapper;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write an implementation of HttpCalloutMock. You can find examples and more information via Google - here is one page to get you started [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

You can build the JSON the `respond` method returns using the same classes that you use to parse the JSON, then turn that data into JSON using `JSON.serialize`.

Make sure that your test class asserts the results by querying the various SObjects produced and verifying the number of SObjects and values in them.